# Angular formly onblur calculation and hide/show fields error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I am trying to perform some calculation on formly onBlur event and after that would like to hide and show the next radio button field.

when I debug everything looks good but on UI I am not able to see the correct behavior.

first is the text input and second field is radio, also I would like to set the label dynamically.

Am I missing something? any other way to set this?

```
   fields [
    {
        "type": "moneyInput",
        "key": "amtRcv",
        "id" : "amtRcv",
        "templateOptions": {
         required: true,
          label:"",
          onBlur: function calcAmount($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {

            var recvAmt = $viewValue;

            if(recvAmt)
            {
              var missingAmount = service.amnt - recvAmt;
 //here trying to set the hide and label for radio field. It is getting    set but not working as expected
              fields[1].hideExpression = "false";
               fields[1].templateOptions.label = 'So, is $' + missingAmount + ' is missing? ';

            } else {
              fiedls[1].hideExpression = "true";

            }
          }
      }
      },
      {
        "type": "radioInput",
        "key": "amnt",
        "id" : "amnt",
        "wrapper" : "requiredField",
        "templateOptions": {
          required: true,
          label:"",
          "options": [
            {
              "name": "Yes",
              "value": true
            },
            {
              "name": "No",
              "value": false
            }
            ]
        }
      }
 ]
```

Comment: better fix the code indentation first

Comment: sorry, have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply set a model flag and check the hideExpression of the next set of radio buttons against it.

for instance, in the onBlur function you would do something like:

```
$scope.model.hideRadioBtn = true;
```

Then in the radioInput field you would set a hideExpression to

```
hideExpression: 'model.hideRadioBtn'
```

Then as soon as this value gets set to true it will hide that field.  I've found this is typically the easiest way to accomplish this without a bunch of extra code involved.  We use this at work quite a bit and has always worked well.

Comment: is there any event which triggers on hide or show of formly element ?